# Autolayout the subviews of a `setFrame:` UIView

Tags: ios, uikit, autolayout

I have a container `UIView`. Its children's positions are managed with autolayout. However, I want to position the container itself **explicitly**.

The container exists within a `UIView` subclass that I call `VideoPreviewView`. The container is named `contentOverlayView`.

Here's my code to add an obvious red child to the container that fills it, except for a 1 pixel margin at the edges:

```
UIView *const redView = [UIView new];
[redView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];
[redView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor redColor]];
[[videoView contentOverlayView] addSubview: redView];

[[videoView contentOverlayView] addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(1@900)-[redView]-(1@900)-|"
  options:0
  metrics:nil
  views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(redView)]];

[[videoView contentOverlayView] addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint
  constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(1@900)-[redView]-(1@900)-|"
  options:0
  metrics:nil
  views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(redView)]];
```

## Setting frame in `layoutSubviews`

My initial approach to keeping the container view positioned within was to simply override `layoutSubviews` for `VideoPreviewView` and explicitly set the frame of the container there, like this:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
  // Other stuff snipped out.
  const CGRect videoBounds = [self videoBounds];
  [_contentOverlayView setFrame: videoBounds];
  [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

…But this didn't work. If I use `recursiveDescription` on `videoView` I get:

```
<VideoPreviewView: 0x146a54f0; frame = (0 0; 320 460); layer = <CALayer: 0x146a5640>>
   | <UIView: 0x145b6610; frame = (0 0; 2 2); layer = <CALayer: 0x145b6680>>
   |    | <UIView: 0x145bff60; frame = (1 1; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x145bffd0>>
```

It has just enough width to respect the margins I required, but the position is completely wrong, and the frame isn't as large as I want.

I used `_autoLayoutTrace` on the container view to try to resolve this and I'm told that the layout is ambiguous:

```
UIWindow:0x145a3a50
|   UIView:0x145a6e60
|   |   HPBezelView:0x1468d580
|   |   |   UIImageView:0x145aab30
|   |   *VideoPreviewView:0x146a54f0
|   |   |   *UIView:0x145b6610- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIView:0x145b6610.minX{id: 5}, UIView:0x145b6610.minY{id: 13}, UIView:0x145b6610.Width{id: 8}, UIView:0x145b6610.Height{id: 16}
|   |   |   |   *UIView:0x145bff60- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIView:0x145bff60.minX{id: 4}, UIView:0x145bff60.minY{id: 12}, UIView:0x145bff60.Width{id: 9}, UIView:0x145bff60.Height{id: 17}
```

This suggested to me that if I'm using autolayout, the frame is ignored, so I need to set the container's frame using autolayout too.

## Adding size constraints

Some other posts and blogs and such also suggest this course of action. So I added some constraints to control the width and height of the container:

```
_contentOverlayWidthConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: contentOverlayView
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                             relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem: nil
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                            multiplier: 1.0
                              constant: 1];

_contentOverlayHeightConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: contentOverlayView
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                             relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem: nil
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                            multiplier: 1.0
                              constant: 1];


[contentOverlayView addConstraints: @[_contentOverlayWidthConstraint, _contentOverlayHeightConstraint]];
```

I updated my `layoutSubviews` method to adjust the "constants" on these constraints:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
  const CGRect videoBounds = [self videoBounds];
  [_contentOverlayView setFrame: videoBounds];
  [_contentOverlayWidthConstraint setConstant: CGRectGetWidth(videoBounds)];
  [_contentOverlayHeightConstraint setConstant: CGRectGetHeight(videoBounds)];

  [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

This works a little better – the red view is visible now and has the correct size, but it is still located at the wrong place. I still get ambiguities from the trace:

```
   UIWindow:0x17d76a00
   |   UIView:0x17d7dfd0
   |   |   HPBezelView:0x17d7d7c0
   |   |   |   UIImageView:0x17d82240
   |   |   *VideoPreviewView:0x17d925e0
   |   |   |   UIView:0x17d96790
   |   |   |   *UIView:0x17d96830- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIView:0x17d96830.minX{id: 9}, UIView:0x17d96830.minY{id: 16}
   |   |   |   |   *UIView:0x17d9ae90- AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT for UIView:0x17d9ae90.minX{id: 8}, UIView:0x17d9ae90.minY{id: 15}
```

… so, the width and height ambiguities have gone, but the position ambiguities remain.

## Adding position constraints

So, I added two more layout constraints to set the container's position:

```
_contentOverlayLeftConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: contentOverlayView
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                             relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem: nil
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                            multiplier: 1.0
                              constant: 0];

_contentOverlayTopConstraint =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: contentOverlayView
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTop
                             relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem: nil
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                            multiplier: 1.0
                              constant: 0];


[contentOverlayView addConstraints: @[_contentOverlayLeftConstraint, _contentOverlayTopConstraint]];
```

And updated `layoutSubviews`:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
  [[self contentView] setFrame: [self bounds]];
  [[self videoPreviewLayer] setFrame: [self bounds]];

  const CGRect videoBounds = [self videoBounds];
  [_contentOverlayWidthConstraint setConstant: CGRectGetWidth(videoBounds)];
  [_contentOverlayHeightConstraint setConstant: CGRectGetHeight(videoBounds)];
  [_contentOverlayLeftConstraint setConstant: CGRectGetMinX(videoBounds)];
  [_contentOverlayTopConstraint setConstant: CGRectGetMinY(videoBounds)];

  [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

## Crash

But when I try to add the new constraints, I get an exception with the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: A constraint cannot be made that sets a location equal to a constant. Location attributes must be specified in pairs'

This I don't get at all. I can't see how I can rectify this.

Can you help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is these lines and similar:

```
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: contentOverlayView
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                             relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                toItem: nil
                             attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                            multiplier: 1.0
                              constant: 0];
```

You cannot set Left / Top equal to a nil item. You must set it to some attribute of another view (typically that would be the left / top of this item's superview, or something that you want to align it with).

Only the Width and Height can be absolute. And even they cannot be 0 (or at least should not be), as you have it here; that makes no sense.

Comment: And do you really want the width and height of this thing to be 1? That's going to be darn near invisible.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the reply. I was just trying that out, and you're absolutely right: It's working perfectly. If I `_autoLayoutTrace` there are no ambiguities now. I'm setting the constants initially to zero because I don't have any more sensible values – I don't know them yet. When the layout is actually determined during `layoutSubviews`, I update them to sensible values before calling [super layoutSubviews] to allow autolayout to occur (I tried to show this in the question – let me know if that's not clear).

Comment: Incidentally – is there a simpler way to achieve this? I wondered if I could use the autoresizing mask somehow, but as I don't have a sensible initial frame for the container, I'm not sure this works.

Comment: On those initial 0 constant values you flagged up – I set up the red square child to have a priority of 900 (not default 1000) on the 1 pixel padding. If I take this out, I get constraint violation warnings when I set up the views, so you were right again :-) This is kind of annoying – it would be nice to be able to set up an I-have-no-idea-what-this-should-be initial value on the basis that I'll update it as soon as `layoutSublayers` is called.

Comment: Actually what you're doing is very sensible, simple, and well within the spirit of auto layout. You may think of it as non simple but in fact you are working in harmony with the system. Constraints may look verbose but they are just boilerplate and they pack a lot of descriptive power. Changing constraints before layout occurs or in `layoutSubviews` is totally legal; there's a WWDC video that demonstrates that very technique.

Comment: You might want to read over this section of my discussion: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_autolayout plus this: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_order_of_layout_events I think you'll find it quite reassuring. :) But ignore the intervening section (about constraints in the nib), as it is outdated.

Comment: Hi again Matt. I've realised something I don't understand here. My view hierarchy is: `Parent -> Container -> RedView`. Adding constraints between `Container` and `RedView` "infected" `Container` with auto-layout. To satisfy auto-layout, further constraints on `Container` are required. This part makes sense. However: the added constraints on `Container` are against `Parent`. Why is it that `Parent` **doesn't** become "infected" and alst require further constraints? Why is auto-layout happy for `Parent` to use its frame, but not for `Container` to do so?

Comment: Explain how Parent gets into the interface please.

Comment: Hmm, sorry – I used different names here from the original question! Using the original names, the hierarchy of views is `videoView -> contentOverlayView -> redView`. `videoView` is an instance of `UIView` subclass `VideoPreviewView`. It creates `contentOverlayView` during its `init`. It has constraints (as discussed) to constrain `contentOverlayView` to be on top of the video port that it presents. `redView` is my debugging thing to test out constraints. It is added to `contentOverlayView` elsewhere along with constraints between it and `contentOverlayView` as in the question.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. I can't explain until you do. How does `videoView` get into the interface.

Comment: Ah – I understand. When I wrote the question, I was instantiating `videoView` in a `UIViewController`s `viewDidLoad` override, setting its frame explicitly, and adding it to the `UIViewController`'s `view`. … Guessing what you might be about to suggest – perhaps it had `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` YES, and so did have sufficient constraints, even though it did become "infected"? I wasn't explicitly setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to NO.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61759/discussion-between-matt-and-benjohn).

Answer (score 2):

[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) has provided a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25985237/2547229) here. I'd like to add a few more points from my implementation that I've found useful.

## Avoiding initial constraint violations

As Matt points out, I create my constraints such that the view has 0 width and height during `init` of the view. I do this because when I create the constraints I don't have any sensible idea about the width or height. Unfortunately, if I add these constraints to a view they are likely to cause a constraint violation.

To avoid this, `init` doesn't add the constraints to a view. I wait until the first time `updateConstraints` is called. Here, I *do* know the correct values for the width and height, so I set those. I *then* add the constraints on to views if I have not already done so. It looks like this:

```
-(void) updateConstraints
{
  const CGRect videoBounds = [self videoBounds];
  [_contentOverlayWidthConstraint setConstant: CGRectGetWidth(videoBounds)];
  [_contentOverlayHeightConstraint setConstant: CGRectGetHeight(videoBounds)];
  [_contentOverlayLeftConstraint setConstant: CGRectGetMinX(videoBounds)];
  [_contentOverlayTopConstraint setConstant: CGRectGetMinY(videoBounds)];

  if(!_constraintsAreAdded)
  {
    [_contentOverlayView addConstraints: @[_contentOverlayWidthConstraint, _contentOverlayHeightConstraint]];
    [self addConstraints: @[_contentOverlayLeftConstraint, _contentOverlayTopConstraint]];
    _constraintsAreAdded = YES;
  }

  [super updateConstraints];
}
```

## Constraint creation shorcuts

I find the `NSLayoutConstraint` method to create individual constraints rather long and unclear. I added a category to make this easier and provide symbolic descriptions of the specific kinds of constraint being created. I'll add more methods to it as they seem useful, but here's what I have so far:

### UIView+Constraints.h

```
@interface UIView (Constraints)
-(NSLayoutConstraint*) widthConstraintWithConstant: (CGFloat) initialWidth;
-(NSLayoutConstraint*) heightConstraintWithConstant: (CGFloat) initialHeight;
-(NSLayoutConstraint*) leftOffsetFromView: (UIView*) view withConstant: (CGFloat) offset;
-(NSLayoutConstraint*) topOffsetFromView: (UIView*) view withConstant: (CGFloat) offset;
@end
```

### UIView+Constraints.m

```
@implementation UIView (Constraints)

-(NSLayoutConstraint*) widthConstraintWithConstant: (CGFloat) initial
{
  return [NSLayoutConstraint
          constraintWithItem: self
          attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
          relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
          toItem: nil
          attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
          multiplier: 1.0
          constant: initial];
}

-(NSLayoutConstraint*) heightConstraintWithConstant: (CGFloat) initial
{
  return [NSLayoutConstraint
          constraintWithItem: self
          attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight
          relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
          toItem: nil
          attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
          multiplier: 1.0
          constant: initial];
}

-(NSLayoutConstraint*) leftOffsetFromView: (UIView*) view withConstant: (CGFloat) offset
{
  return [NSLayoutConstraint
          constraintWithItem: self
          attribute: NSLayoutAttributeLeft
          relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
          toItem: view
          attribute: NSLayoutAttributeLeft
          multiplier: 1.0
          constant: offset];
}

-(NSLayoutConstraint*) topOffsetFromView: (UIView*) view withConstant: (CGFloat) offset
{
  return [NSLayoutConstraint
          constraintWithItem: self
          attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTop
          relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
          toItem: view
          attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTop
          multiplier: 1.0
          constant: offset];
}

@end
```